# Eliminate loop and use Linq instead

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreach

Say I have a List as below:

```
 List<R> lstR = GetR();
```

Now I want a Linq statement to get menus assigned to `R`, I achieved this by using a loop and then using Linq to get the menus as below:

```
 List<int> ids = new List<int>();
 foreach (R r in lstR)
 {
   ids.Add(r.Id);
 }

 menu = (from s in db.Menu
         where ids.Contains(s.R.Id)
         select s.MenuText).Distinct();
```

Now as far as I know the above is two loop(Linq is using internal loop). would I be able to combine these two statements i.e. not do the first loop to get the ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both `lstR` and `db.Menu` are either in-memory data sets (Linq-to-Objects) or `IQueryable` collections from your database, you can do this:

```
menu = 
    (from s in db.Menu
     where lstR.Select(r => r.Id)
               .Contains(s.R.Id)
     select s.MenuText)
    .Distinct();
```

Or this:

```
menu = 
    (from s in db.Menu
     join r in lstR on s.R.Id equals r.Id
     select s.MenuText)
    .Distinct();
```

However, since `List<R>` exists in memory and `db.Menu` is an `IQueryable`, you're options are limited. You could materialize `db.Menu` into an `IEnumerable`, so you can process it in memory:

```
List<R> lstR = GetR();
menu = 
    (from s in db.Menu.AsEnumerable()
     join r in lstR on s.R.Id equals r.Id
     select s.MenuText)
    .Distinct();
```

But, this can be costly if there are a lot of records. It's better to do something like this, which admittedly doesn't look much different from what you already have:

```
List<R> lstR = GetR();
var ids = lstR.Select(r => r.Id).ToList(); // or .ToArray();
menu = 
    (from s in db.Menu
     where ids.Contains(s.R.Id)
     select s.MenuText)
    .Distinct();
```

But in truth, the best option is to see if you can refactor `GetR` so that it returns an `IQueryable<R>` from your database. That way you can use both of the first two options without needing to materialize any sets into memory first. And by the way, once you've done that *and* set up navigation properties, you can probably do something like this:

```
IQueryable<R> lstR = GetR();
menu = 
    (from r in lstR
     from s in r.Menus
     select s.MenuText)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: +1 Tried the first solution but am getting: Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestProject.Models.R'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: +1 Finally someone that offers a join. Imo the best readability.

Comment: +1 For the join option, but depends on the amount of id's that are in `lstR` else this will be much slower than a HashSet lookup.

Comment: @Sam I've added some more detail about why you're having troubles mixing in-memory and database objects in the same query.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thank you very much your last two recommendation worked...but as you recommended I used IQueryable :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like.

```
menu = (from s in db.Menu
        where lstR.Select(item => item.Id).Contains(s.R.Id)
        select s.MenuText).Distinct();
```

But i wouldnt combine those two statements, because if you use a HashSet it will speed up:

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(lstR);

menu = (from s in db.Menu
     where ids.Contains(s.R.Id)
     select s.MenuText).Distinct();
```

This will be faster i guess. The problem with the first one is, every `s` in `db.Menu` The list is iterated for creating a list of id's `select()`.

Comment: Why mix up the Linq and Linq extension methods like that?

Comment: @Grant Thomas - Because the first question was how to combine those two.

Comment: In terms of logic, yeah, but I don't see why one would interlace like this unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: This was, because of the question. I agree to you, but this was for example.

Answer (score 1):

You coud use the linq projection method `Select()`:

```
ids = lstR.Select(p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Would this allow you to do `lstR.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(s.R.ID)`? And therefore combine the two queries?

Comment: Absolutely. That's the power of linq.

Answer (score 1):

```
menu = db.Menu.Where(s => GetR().Select(r => r.Id).Contains(s.R.Id))
                     .Select(s => s.MenuText)
                     .Distinct();
```

but it will be to complex. It will be better if you'l write like this

```
        var ids = GetR().Select(r => r.Id);

        menu = db.Menu.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.R.Id))
                      .Select(s => s.MenuText)
                      .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Join**

```
var result = (from s in db.Menu
              join r in lstR on s.Id equals r.ID
              select s.MenuText).Distinct();
```